# running different functions depending on variable given to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to have run three functions: 1 & 2 can do something and 3 does either 1 or 2 depending on a bool's value. Function 1 & 2 work fine and return what I want when I type  function1(10)  in the console. Don't need to print, just return. The if clause in function3 seems to work when I put print statements in it, but doesn't return anything.

```
def function1(n)
    result1 = do things to (n)
    return result1

def function2(n)
    result2 = do other things to (n)
    return result2 

def function3(n, aboolvariable=True)
    if aboolvariable:
        function1(n)
    else:
        function2(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `funtion3` you dont return values only calling them, you need to `return` those results:

```
def function3(n, aboolvariable=True)
    if aboolvariable:
        return function1(n)
    else:
        return function2(n)
```

also you can use `isinstance(n, bool)`instead of passing `aboolvariable` parameter to your function

Answer (score 0):

Right now function3 simply calls func1 or func2 based on your boolean.
In order for func3 to return the result of the selected function you must add a `return` statement to it.

tldr: add a `return` statement to function3

```
def function3(n, aboolvariable=True)
    if aboolvariable:
        return function1(n)
    return function2(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The if clause in function3 seems to work when I put print statements
> in it, but doesn't return anything.
> but doesn't return anything

Function to be able return something, Simply use `return` keyword before the thing you want to return in your example `function1` if `aboolvariable` True else return `function2`.

```py
def function3(n, aboolvariable=True)
    return function1(n) if aboolvariable else return function2(n)
```

Don't forget to invoke the Function `function3` by calling it inside print:

```py
print(function3(1)) #which call func1 by default aboolvariable=True
print(function3(1, False)) #call func2 since second Argument is False
```